# ASP.Net vertical alignment of controls in a panel

Tags: asp.net, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have a Panel with the following:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="101px">
    Day
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="24px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    &nbsp;Hour
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</asp:Panel>
```

The texts ("Day" and "Hour") seem to have a different vertical alignment with respect to the dropdownboxes

[alt text http://img215.imageshack.us/img215/115/paneld.jpg](http://img215.imageshack.us/img215/115/paneld.jpg)

How do I fix this easily?

Comment: On Panel1 set the vertical alignment to use the top of the text, with a `style="vertical-align: text-top;"` attribute.

Comment: I know I've seen this happen before, but now I can't reproduce it with your code snippet. Also, are you intentionally setting the height of the panel and drop down? If not, you could remove them.

Answer (score 2):

One solution I stumbled on to was to enclose the text and DropDownLists in a Table with a single row and have a separate cell for each text/dropbox. Works like a charm.

Comment: Why use a table when SEO-friendly markup is just as simple and free?

Comment: No!  Please, no!  Table-layout is so 1991.

Answer (score 1):

It's really this simple:

```
<div>
    Day
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    Hour
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you actually try the div, and if so, what browser us giving you this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you tried this or not...

```
<div style="vertical-align:top"> 
    Day 
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" style="vertical-align:bottom"> 
    </asp:DropDownList> 
    Hour 
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" style="vertical-align:bottom"> 
    </asp:DropDownList>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adjusting the vertical alignment using the style attribute?
http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

Comment: These are ASP.Net controls, I'm not sure how you can apply CSS styles on these.

Comment: @Nikhil: Add a `style="..."` attribute. You won't get Intellisense for it, but it will render correctly. Instead of inline styles though you'd be better to use the CssClass property and put the styles in a stylesheet.

Comment: Tried `style` out, but even after trying different alignment options, I could not get it properly aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Try forming your tags as    or add some whitespace around them. It may be wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

That other answer had formatting issues. Here is it again.

Not sure you tried it or not:

```
<div style="vertical-align:top"> 
  Day 
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" style="vertical-align:bottom"> 
  </asp:DropDownList> 
   Hour 
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" style="vertical-align:bottom"> 
   </asp:DropDownList> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this if you haven"t

```
<div style="vertical-align:top">
Day 
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" style="vertical-align:bottom">
</asp:DropDownList>
Hour 
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" style="vertical-align:bottom>
</asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Comment: Somehow, div's style attribute won't work in FF and Chrome. If that's the case, try vertical-align on individual elements.